# Custom header in spring-security-oauth2-client by RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I made a rest-application that receives a request from the Client and goes to the resource server, simultaneously authorizing via OAuth2 using client_Credentials
But the authorization server, instead of the default request, also waits for the UserId in header, which must be filled with data from the Client's request

I use this bean implementation:

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebClientConfig {
        @Bean
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
                ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                            .clientCredentials()
                            .build();
            DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
            authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
            return authorizedClientManager;
        }
    }
```

I request an access token via OAuth2AutorizeRequest:

```
    OAuth2AutorizeRequest oAuth2AutorizeRequest = OAuth2AutorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("test").principal("test").build();
    OAuth2AccessToken token = authorizedClientManager.authorize(oAuth2AutorizeRequest).getAccessToken;
```

How can I add a UserId headers to the Authorization header when sending a POST request, which will be filled from the Client request?

Example:

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: auth-server:1111
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic bWVzc2FnaW5nLWNsaWVudDpzZWNyZXQ=
UserId : naW5nLbWVzcVudDpzZ
grant_type=client_credentials&scope=message.read
```

Comment: have you tried to set it as an attribute ? `oAuth2AutorizeRequest.getAttributes().put("userId", request.getHeader("UserId"))`.

Comment: It's nod add header

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a `@Service` like that (provided that you have an OAuth2 client registration labeled "machin" in your Spring Boot properties):

```java
@Service
public class ClientCredentialsService {
    
    private final WebClient tokenEndpoint;
    private final String spaceDelimitedScopes;
    
    private Map<String, AccessToken> cachedTokens = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    public ClientCredentialsService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepo) {
        final var clientRegistration = clientRegistrationRepo.findByRegistrationId("machin");
        
        // According to your question, this should contain at least message.read
        this.spaceDelimitedScopes = clientRegistration.getScopes().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        
        // In client_credentials flow, according to the spec,
        // the access token should be fetched by calling the token endpoint 
        // with client_id and client_secret passed as Basic Authorization header
        // See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4
        tokenEndpoint= WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(clientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getTokenUri())
            .filter(ExchangeFilterFunctions.basicAuthentication(clientRegistration.getClientId(), clientRegistration.getClientSecret()))
            .build();
    }

    public Mono<String> getAccessToken(String userId) {
        final var now = Instant.now();

        // cache cleanup
        this.cachedTokens = cachedTokens.entrySet().stream().filter(at -> at.getValue().expiryTime().isAfter(now)).collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        
        final var cached = cachedTokens.get(userId);
        if(cached != null) {
            return Mono.just(cached.value);
        }
        
        // This is a call to an OAuth2 token endpoint,
        // using client_credentials flow and a custom header
        // See the spec linked above for the request body (content of the application/x-www-form-urlencoded body)
        return tokenEndpoint.post()
                .header("userId", userId)
                .body(BodyInserters
                        .fromFormData("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                        .with("scope", spaceDelimitedScopes))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Map.class)
                .map(resp -> {
                    final var token = (String) resp.get("access_token");
                    final var expiry = now.plusSeconds((Long) resp.get("expires_in") - 2);
                    this.cachedTokens.put(userId, new AccessToken(token, expiry));
                    return token;
                });
    }
    
    public Mono<WebClient> getAuthorizedClient(String userId) {
        return getAccessToken(userId).map(accessToken ->  WebClient
                .builder()
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer %s".formatted(accessToken))
                .build());
    }
    
    static private record AccessToken(String value, Instant expiryTime) {}
}
```

Usage as follow:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {
    private static final String OAUTH2_RESOURCE_URI = "https://other.service/some-resource";

    private final ClientCredentialsService clientCredentialsService;

    @GetMapping("/something-from-an-oauth2-resource-server")
    public String getSomething(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return clientCredentialsService
                .getAuthorizedClient(request.getHeader("UserId"))
                .flatMap(client -> client
                        .get()
                        .uri(OAUTH2_RESOURCE_URI)
                        .retrieve()
                        // This should be changed with the type of DTO returned by the OAuth2 delegate
                        .bodyToMono(String.class))
                .block();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I check the formed post-request? For some reason, headers and body with logging.level.root = trace - not show me this request

Comment: Web client is reactive. Have you called `.block()` in your test code to subscribe to the request?

Comment: *.block()* on call tokenEndpoint? And why in  *final var expiry = now.plusSeconds((Long) resp.get("expires_in") - 2);* are you do *- 2* on the end?

Comment: You are in a servlet (synchronized app, not a reactive one) => you have to subscribe to a Mono (`.block()`) for the inner code to be executed. In my sample, it is done after `flatMap` a second Mono in the controller method. The `-2` seconds on expiry is because network can be slow and you don't want to return a token expiring within the next second. You could completely remove caching logic too.